# "Could not perform this request with your account." -- iOS error

Tags: support, ios-app

I sometimes use the iOS Stack Exchange app. This has been working for years, but suddenly every time I try to take an action, I get a pop-up error message that says:

```
Request failed
Could not perform this request with
your account. Please try logging back
in. If this persists, let us know on meta.
```

This seems to happen whenever I try to take any action (specifically, this happened when I tried upvoting, posting a comment, and posting an answer).  I can navigate the site and read posts normally, and I am logged in.

I did log out and log back in again, as the error message suggested, but it didn't fix the problem.  (I also restarted my phone since I upgraded to iOS 16.1, just in case that was the issue -- but it wasn't.)

I haven't made any changes in my account. Login is via a Stack Exchange username and password.

(I understand that the iOS app is no longer under active development, but I thought it was supposed to be working still?)

Needless to say, I posted this via my computer rather than on my phone.

---

By the way, the reason I'm posting in meta is that that's what the error message said to do.  If there's a better way of sending in an error report, I'd appreciate a pointer!

Comment: Personally, I do not use SE on a mobile - so I don't follow this that closely. But I guess it might be useful to check this announcement: [Mobile app infrastructure being decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026). (At the moment, it is now among the featured posts in the [community bulletin](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-bulletin/info).)

Comment: The error message "request failed" was recently mention in this question, too: [Cannot post comments on SE app on iOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383238) (on [meta.se]).

Comment: @MartinSleziak -- Thanks, I hadn't seen those posts (and the search I made looked too specifically for the exact error I was seeing).  It looks like the app is finally going away.  If you'd like to turn your comments into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I will add that recently I've noticed that an announcement about a different app was posted [on stackapps](https://stackapps.com/questions/9551/crew-for-exchange-2-0-full-ios-native-client) and [on MathOverflow Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5087/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-app-for-ios/5487#5487) - but since this isn't officially supported by Stack Exchange and created by someone else, perhaps it's reasonable to be cautious before trying it. (There doesn't seem to be much feedback on it.)

Comment: Since you've mentioned the search, I will just add that I tried to search *networkwide* [like this](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bios-app%5D+%22Request+failed%22+created%3A2022-01-01..), i.e., with some keywords from the error message, the tag (ios-app) and - after seeing that there are several results - restricting the search only to recent ones. But it is certainly useful to have some posts related to this on the Mathematics Meta, too - not only on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is CW - feel free to edit it if you have something useful to add or if you see some suitable changes. (At the moment, it just summarizes what has already been said in the comments - following the [OP's suggestion to post the comments as an answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/165780).)

- A brief summary of the situation is that the mobile apps are going away.
- Not too long ago, this announcement was posted on Meta Stack Exchange: [Mobile app infrastructure being decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026). (At the moment, it is now among the featured posts in the [community bulletin](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-bulletin/info).)
- The same error message was recently mentioned in this question, too: [Cannot post comments on SE app on iOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383238) (on Meta Stack Exchange.
- Recently an announcement about a different was posted on stackapps: [Crew for Exchange 2.0 (Full iOS native client)](https://stackapps.com/q/9551). It was mentioned [on MathOverflow Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5087/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-app-for-ios/5487#5487), too. But since this isn't officially supported by Stack Exchange and created by someone else, perhaps it's reasonable to be cautious before trying it. (So far, there doesn't seem to be much feedback on it.)