# I am unable to add comments to questions via the mobile app

Tags: support, ios-app

I can add comments via Chrome Browser on my iMac however, I am unable to do so from my iPhone mobile using the Stack Exchange App. It lets me type in the comments but fails when I submit it. It asked me to try logging in again which I did but that still failed.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you read this:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026 ?

Comment: @postmortes - no, I was not aware of the plan to kill the app off - sad days. I use it quite a lot, especially to keep an eye on any interesting Q's as they arise. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I really have to wonder if they undercounted the usage somehow. Or if not, maybe perhaps our community uses it to a higher percentage than others.

Comment: Even  if you don't check main meta, [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35249/could-not-perform-this-request-with-your-account-ios-error) is recent enough it should be found when making any effort to check before asking.

Comment: Abandonment of the mobile apps (iPhone and Android) should be understood in the context of the [responsive web redesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370964/now-live-a-fully-responsive-profile) that was initiated five years ago and went live across the network one year ago.  I have found the responsive design satisfactory on my (Android) phone's browser, but there are a few quirks to learn.